# How to use string.split() without foreach()?

Tags: scala

Write a program in Scala that reads an String from the keyboard and counts the number of characters, ignoring if its UpperCase or LowerCase
ex: Avocado
R: A = 2; v = 1; o = 2; c = 1; d = 2;

So, i tried to do it with two fors iterating over the string, and then a conditional to transform the character in the position (x) to Upper and compare with the character in the position (y) which is the same position... basically i'm transforming the same character so i can increment in the counter ex: Ava -> A = 2; v = 1;

But with this logic when i print the result it comes with:
ex: Avocado
R: A = 2; v = 1; o = 2; c = 1; a = 2; d = 1; o = 2;
its repeting the same character Upper or Lower in the result...
so my teacher asked us to resolve this using the split method and yield of Scala but i dunno how to use the split without forEach() that he doesnt allow us to use.

sorry for the bad english

```
object ex8 {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Write a string")
    var string = readLine()
    var cont = 0

    for (x <- 0 to string.length - 1) {
      for (y <- 0 to string.length - 1) {
        if (string.charAt(x).toUpper == string.charAt(y).toUpper)
          cont += 1
      }
      print(string.charAt(x) + " = " + cont + "; ")
      cont = 0
    }
  }
}
```

But with this logic when i print the result it comes with:
ex: Avocado
R: A = 2; V = 1; o = 2; c = 1; a = 2; d = 1; o = 2;

Comment: Probably doesn't answer your question (and I don't understand why `split` and `yield` are needed at all), but I would use a different approach altogether: maintain a Map: character -> the number of times this character appears. This Map can be filled with one foreach-loop.

Comment: thanks, i will try this approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala 2.13 has added a very handy method to cover this sort of thing.

```
inputStr.groupMapReduce(_.toUpper)(_ => 1)(_+_)
        .foreach{case (k,v) => println(s"$k = $v")}
//A = 2
//V = 1
//C = 1
//O = 2
//D = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

It might be easier to group the individual elements of the `String` (i.e. a collection of `Char`s, made case-insensitive with `toLower`) to aggregate their corresponding `size` using `groupBy/mapValues`:

```
"Avocado".groupBy(_.toLower).mapValues(_.size)
// res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,Int] =
//   Map(a -> 2, v -> 1, c -> 1, o -> 2, d -> 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Scala 2.11

Tried with classic word count approach of map => group => reduce

```
val exampleStr = "Avocado R"

exampleStr.
  toLowerCase.
  trim.
  replaceAll(" +","").
  toCharArray.map(x => (x,1)).groupBy(_._1).
  map(x => (x._1,x._2.length))
```

Answer :

```
exampleStr: String = Avocado R

res3: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,Int] = 
Map(a -> 2, v -> 1, c -> 1, r -> 1, o -> 2, d -> 1)
```